# How to get the starting and ending positions of a paragraph in tkinter text box?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, tags, paragraph

I have created a text editor with **tkinter.Text** and I am facing a problem where my program detects which paragraph currently user is on i.e. it detects the starting and ending index of the paragraph where the current insertion point is.

I also searched in previously asked questions but couldn't find any references to paragraph detection in the tkinter.Text widget (bcoz solutions mentioned on the web seem to work for a single string, not for line.column as in tkinter.Text widget.)

So it would be very very helpful if anybody could please elaborate **how to get the indexes of the start and end of a pargraph in tkinter.Text widget.**

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote some code that should help you. If something is not clear - ask.

```py
import tkinter as tk

 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
 
tb = tk.Text(root, width=600, height=600)
tb.pack()
 
tags = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
now_tag = 0
tb.tag_config("red", foreground="red", background="black")
tb.tag_config("blue", foreground="blue", background="black")
tb.tag_config("green", foreground="green", background="black")
tb.tag_config("yellow", foreground="yellow", background="black")
 
 
def update_tb(event=None):
    global now_tag
 
    tb.tag_add(tags[now_tag], "{0} linestart".format(tk.INSERT), "{0} lineend".format(tk.INSERT))
    now_tag = 1 + now_tag if len(tags) - 1 > now_tag else 0
 
 
root.bind('<Return>', update_tb)
root.bind('<Control_L>', update_tb)
root.bind('<Shift_L>', update_tb)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. How does this identify paragraphs?

Comment: This is not for paragraphs this for current line and so of course it doesn't identify paragraphs.